# How can I access the BIOS on my Advent PC

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, bios

I am trying to learn how to use Android App inventor and have been told to enable VT - x in my BIOS security settings. I understand that to enter the BIOS I have to press certain keys when I boot up.

However I have checked my computer manual and there is no indication of which keys to press. I have also watched the VDU during cold and warm reboots and the computer does not indicate which keys might get me into the BIOS if I press them. I have tried many, many cold restarts pressing all the F keys from 1 to 10 individually and I have tried the escape key and enter key and delete key. None seem to work. My keyboard is connected via the old-style purple-colored connector. It is not wireless.

My computer is an Advent Desktop PC; I think it is model 50S.

- I am running Windows 10 Home Edition version 1607
- OS Build 14393.321
- Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 - 3770 CPU @ 3.40GHz
- Installed: RAM 16.0 GB
- System type: 64 bit operating system, x64-based processor

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Am I pressing the wrong keys? What is the correct procedure for getting into the BIOS?

Answer (score 1):

Usually you could boot into the BIOS setup with <kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>Del</kbd>.

When the system is started up, keep pressing the key continuously, or when restarting the system just hold down the key until the BIOS setup comes up.

It might be also some other keys like <kbd>F4</kbd>, <kbd>F6</kbd>, or <kbd>F8</kbd>.

There might also be other keys enabled depending on the system.